# ASP.NET + VB.NET - How to get a value from a HTML string

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

How do I get the value from a HTML string using VB.NET?

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px">
<span style="font-family: tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold">

This is the text I want to catch!!!

</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It can parse both full documents and document fragments and let you query these using XPath like syntax.

The source download comes with many example projects.

Answer (score 0):

1- Turn the span to a server object:

```
<span ID="span1" runat="server"> .... </span>
```

2- InnerText property to get the text reside inside the span between > and < :

```
Dim str as string = span1.InnerHTML
```